# Update query MongoDB-Java if array field doesn't exist or exists

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
{
  "name": null,
  "registrationNo": null,
  "address": [
    {
      "street`": 0,
      "landmark": null,
      "city": null,
      "district": null,
      "state": null,
    }
  ]
}
```

Consider above JSON structure. Field 'address' can be present in JSON, not sure.

I want to update 'address' field with following condition :

1. If field present and value is null, then add new array with values.
2. If field present and some values are there in array, add new values    to array
3. If field not present, add field for array 'address', and then add values.

Please help me with query for MongoDB Java driver. Above checks should be done in DAO level.

Comment: I think i need to use $set or $push.
If array has data call $push else $set.

But how to check whether array has data

Comment: Also is the [tag:java] tag intentional?

Comment: Sorry, i will remove java tag